# Ajax check username not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have created a sign up page on a website, I'm currently trying to implement an AJAX username check function. My issue is that it doesn't run at all when a username is being typed in the input field.

Any help would be grateful.

**Sign up page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sign up Fabio's</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Images/Pizza.ico">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Username").keyup(function (e) {
        var username = $(this).val();
            $.post('usernamecheck.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
              $("#user-result").html(data);

        }
    }); 
});
</script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="Content2">
<form action="newuser.php" class="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
           <label for="Title">Title </label><br>
        <select name="Title" >
                 <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                 <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                 <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                 <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                 </select></br>
        <label for="FirstName">First name</label> <input type="text" name="FirstName" required></br>
        <label for ="LastName">Last name</label><input type="text" name="LastName" required></br>
        <label for="Username">Username</label> <input type="text" name="Username" required><span id ="user-result"></span>
        <label for="Email">Email</label> <input type="email" name="Email" required>
        <label for ="Password1">Password</label><input type="password" name="Password1" id ="Password1" required></br>
            <label for="Password2">Confirm Password </label><input type="password" name="Password2" id="Password2" required></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"> 
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**usernamecheck.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"]))
{
    include 'dbconnect.php';
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Id From Userv2 WHERE Username = '$username'");

    $username_true = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($username_true >0){
        echo "Sorry $username has been taken";
        }
    else{
        echo "$username is available";
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: **!! SQL INJECTION ALERT !!** - Please use prepared statements or at least escape your data before including it in a SQL query string.

Comment: I agree with @ThiefMaster use the [`mysqli_prepare()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) function to prepare statements. (Using parameterized statements practically separates the value from the query. This case, you don't need to escape data.

Comment: add id="Username" to the username input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: keyUp is not assigned to the input field, make sure the input field ID for username is id="Username"

Also try this code below. I added a console log to see if the post function will be reached and executed. Let me know if the post is reached in the console

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Username").keyup(function (e) {
        var username = $(this).val();
            $.post('usernamecheck.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
              $("#user-result").html(data);
console.log('the post is done');

        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this code but it hasn't made a difference. It still doesn't run

Comment: I just checked the console and found that my jquery url source was incorrect. I've changed it and it has solved my problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing $.post(). try with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Username").keyup(function (e) {
        var username = $(this).val();
            $.post('usernamecheck.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
              $("#user-result").html(data);
        }); // closes $.post()
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**WARNING:** You have a SQL Injection error, in usernamecheck.php:

```
    $username = $_POST["username"];
```

Replace by:

```
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["username"]);
```